# Firebase Conditional/Optional Querying

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I'm relatively new to Firebase and am trying to create a mini-wrapper for me to query through my database.

My problem is, I am not sure how to add conditional queries sch as orderByChild...

```
/* Available Arguments:
 *  - key: Order using a child key
 *  - firstAmt: Only get the first x elements
 *  - lastAmt: Only get the last x elements
 *  - startAt: Get elements starting from index x
 *  - endAt: Get elements ending at index x
 */
// Not providing anything will give the first 15 elements
function getProjects(arg, callback, errorCB) {
    if (!arg) arg = {};
    if (!arg.firstAmt) arg.firstAmt = 15;

    var obj = firebase.database().ref('projects');
    if (arg.key) {
        obj.orderByChild(arg.key);
    }
    if (arg.firstAmt) {
        obj.limitToFirst(arg.firstAmt);
    }
    if (arg.lastAmt) {
        obj.limitToLast(arg.lastAmt);
    }
    if (arg.startAt) {
    obj.startAt(arg.startAt);
    }
    if (arg.endAt) {
        obj.endAt(arg.endAt);
    }

    obj.once('value').then((snapshot) => { callback(snapshot.val())}).catch(errorCB);
 }
```

When I call getProjects using {firstAmt: 1} I get every item in my database, rather than JUST the first one.

I don't know if it's the right way to go about it, but I feel like testing for every use case (arg.key && arg.firstAmt...) might be overdoing it.

Thanks!

Comment: i think `limitToFirst`, `limitToLast`, `startAt` and `endAt` only work when using with `orderByChild` along.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it [http://i.imgur.com/MlzmLVs.png](http://i.imgur.com/MlzmLVs.png). I used key and firstAmt 1, which should only give me one value, but it gives me all of them (I only have three for testing).

Comment: Can u get a screenshot of your `projects` object?

Answer (score 0):

`limitToFirst` `limitToLast` `startAt` `endAt` `equalTo`  only works with `orderByKey` `orderByChild` or `orderByValue`

So I suggest you to change your code to:

```
if (arg.key) {
    obj.orderByChild(arg.key);
} else {
    obj.orderByKey();
}
```

This should give you the snapshot till first 15 elements.

Comment: I did what you told me and used `getProjects({ firstAmt: 1 }, (value) => {
   console.log(value)
  }, console.error);` and it didn't work... I am still getting 3 values.

Edit: Even when calling with {firstAmt: 1, key: 'name'} it still gives me my 3 values instead of one.